# Update a field in an array of subdocuments for ALL records

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I first created my site I didn't know MongoDB did case sensitive searching, among many other things, and I'm trying to fix the problems.

I've already updated the code to alter the user input before it's saved so it is lowercase AND trimmed of extra spaces.

I can easily update a collection of users from the mongo shell, and then I'm good to go there, but I have another collection that needs updating and it looks like this:

Registration Data Object:

```
{
event: string,
field: string,
users: [string],
players: [
  first: string,
  last: string,
  email: string
]
}
```

If it's possible to update the players.email field for ALL registrations by trimming it and making it lowercase from the mongo shell, I'd love to do that.  But I don't think it is, and I've had trouble doing it from mongoose (using Node.js backend, AngularJS frontend).

I was thinking something like this, but I get Type error: Registration.save is not a function:

```
module.exports.regUpdateAll = function(req, res) {
  console.log('UPDATE ALL REGISTRATIONS');
    Registration.find().exec((err, reg) => {
      reg.forEach((reg) => {
        for(var i = 0; i < reg.players.length; i++) { 
          reg.players[i].email = reg.players[i].email.toLowerCase().trim(); 
        }
      });
      console.log(reg);
      Registration.save(reg).then((err, response) => {
        if(!err) {
          res.status(200).send(response);
        } else {
          console.log(err);
          res.status(500).send(err);
        }
      });
    });     
};
```

How can I fix this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call .save() from the object of Registration model. for example

```
Registration.find().exec((err, regtrations) => {
    regtrations.forEach((reg) => {
        reg.players =
            reg.players.map( p=> {
                p.email = p.email.toLowerCase().trim();
                return p;
            })

        console.log(reg);
        reg.markModified("players");
        reg.save( (error)=> { 
            //do something
        })
    })
  });
```

Comment: Oh, ok.  I didn't realize I had to save each one individually.  I thought there was a way to save the entire updated array of objects at one time.

Comment: This worked!  I just had to specify all the other fields in reg.players when mapping or it didn't like it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I GOT IT!  This took ALL DAY, but I finally got it to work.  I could NOT get it to work based on the value of has_signed, but I was able to do it this way:

```
this.adminService.GetUnsignedWaivers()
    .subscribe((data: []) => {
      this.players = data;
      this.players.forEach((p) => {
        p.waivers =
            p.waivers.map( w=> {
              if(w.signatureUrl.length>0) {
                w.url = w.signatureUrl;
                w.message = "View Waiver";
              } 
                return w;
            });
    });
    this.size = this.players.length;
    console.log(this.players);
  });
```

[image: Now it displays View Waiver and the correct link for folks who signed.]

I just don't understand WHY.